# How to add a small delay to the get script function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Hello I have a working get script function, but I would like to put in a small delay so the script loads on my page after 500ms

Heres the working script:

```
jQuery.getScript( "https://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
                console.log( data ); // Data returned
                console.log( textStatus ); // Success
                console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
                console.log( "Load was performed." );
            });
```

What method can I do to create a 500ms delay?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you delaying?  `delay()` is for jquery animations and is not a replacement for `setTimeout`

Comment: I thought delay would work. Im interested in any method that will load the function after 500ms

Comment: Do you mean execute the getScript or that performs the success method?

Comment: execute the getScript after 500ms

Comment: Use the `setTimeout` function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delay any execution of scripts on a page with the `setTimeout` function. In your case:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery.getScript( "https://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
                console.log( data ); // Data returned
                console.log( textStatus ); // Success
                console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
                console.log( "Load was performed." );
            });
}, 500);
```